# Custom Website Messaging System Tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, message

I'm a an asp.net/c# newbie trying to create a very basic messaging system between users in a website.
The idea is to build a very basic messaging system that will give an admin the option to send messages to the users , delete older messages , notify a user when there's an unread message etc.

I'm having (surprisingly) a really hard time finding a relevant tutorial on this subject and was hoping maybe something here can direct me to the right location.

Thank you.

Comment: You must at least attempt the system - we are here to solve specific problems not write entire sub systems for you Ned. There are too many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I'm not looking for a ready made solution , just the url for a tutorial that can help me learn what i need to know in order to create my own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a chat application using ASP.NET web forms. It's long, but it's thorough, and should get you started.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27384/Build-a-Web-Chat-Application-using-ASP-Net-3-5-LIN

### UPDATE

A private messaging system is pretty straight forward. The components you'll need to interface are as follows.

1. Some type of persistent storage (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server)
2. A database schema that supports threads (i.e. a table that references itself for replies). This will make the creation easy, you will simply reference another `pm` for a reply, and thus you will get a natural threading hierarchy.
3. Some type of ORM to access the database, I'm going to recommend [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It's what Stack Overflow uses, and quite frankly, it's the fastest and most complete API I've ever used -- and believe me when I say I've **used a lot**!
4. Some type of authentication system (e.g. *[Windows for intranet](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx)* or *[forms for internet](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/using-basic-forms-authentication-in-aspnet)*).
5. A web form for listing, creating, and viewing the messages. To keep things simple just make that three different web forms. This web form will leverage the currently logged in user to determine what PM's to list.

Comment: I think he don't want to have a chat. More a private messaging system

Comment: @Raubi, you may be correct (though that's not terribly evident in the question). However, the basics of any messaging system exist in this tutorial. How you persist, or don't persist, those messages is what turns the system into something more than a chat application.

Comment: Well, I think building a realtime chat system is much more harder than just a simple private messaging system.

Comment: I am trying to create a private messaging system , i apologize if that wasn't clear. But i'll take all the help i can get so - thanks Michael!